# Ajax call with Zend Framework 2

Tags: ajax, zend-framework2

I am trying to call an action in a controller via an ajax request and it works but it also loads the layout twice and I am getting this notice: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." The url where the ajax request is being sent at is /admin/errors.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("input").on("click", function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo $this->url('admin', array('action' => 'geterror')); ?>",
                data: { error_type: $("input:checked").val() },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#view-errors').html(data + "<br>");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

and the code in the action:

```
public function geterrorAction()
{
    if (!$user = $this->identity()) {
        return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/login/log');
    }

    $user = $this->identity();
    $layout = $this->layout();

    $layout->setTerminal(true);

    echo ErrorView::viewErrors($_POST['error_type']);
}
```

Here is a image to better help explain.[image]

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Add a blank layout file inside layout directory.

use `$this->layout('layout/blank');` inside the action of the controller. This will set a blank layout.

```
public function geterrorAction()
{
   $this->layout('layout/blank');
   // .... other codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting the terminal true on the view model

```
public function geterrorAction()
{
    if (!$user = $this->identity()) {
        return $this->redirect()->toUrl('/login/log');
    }

    $user = $this->identity();
    $layout = $this->layout();
    echo ErrorView::viewErrors($_POST['error_type']);
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTerminal(true);
    return $view;
}
```